# Derivative of the matrix exponential with respect to its matrix argument

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential, gateaux-derivative

I was trying to find the Frechet derivative of $f = \exp(X)$, where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive definite. I thought it ought to be $\exp(X)$.

I see results where the derivative is with respect to a scalar argument, but this question has not been asked before.

I tried to see if I could find $Df_X$ starting with 
$Df_X[H] = \exp(X+H) - \exp(X)$.  If I can show that the right hand side evaluates to $I + XH + X^2H/2 + \ldots = \exp(X)H$, I am done.

After I use the series definition, however,  I am lost  because I see no reason to  assume that $A$ and $H$ commute.

Please help.

**EDIT**
Following the suggestion in the comment, I try to compute the Gateaux derivative as $\exp(X + tH)$ by writing down the first few terms.

$\exp(X+tH) = I + (X + tH) + (X^2 + tXH + tHX + t^2H^2)/2 + \cdots$

$\dfrac{d}{dt}\exp(X+tH)\Big|_{t=0} = H + (XH+HX)/2 + \cdots$

And now am stuck again. It seems the expression on the right cannot be rearranged to give what I want.
I think it  is the derivative of the trace of the exponential, not the exponential itself that yields $\exp(X)$

Comment: Try something simpler like $X^2$.  You will see that its Frechet derivative is not $2X$!

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Yes, I am aware its  XH + HX . So if my conjecture is wrong ,what is the  matrix derivative of the exponential map then ?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Remember that your derivative has to be a map from $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.  So it is quite likely something quite horrible.

Comment: You can do it yourself. Really, really carefully write the initial terms in $\exp (X + t H)$ for real $t$ This formalism gives the directional or Gateux derivative...

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, not so bad if you write it as a series....

Comment: @WillJagy: I started with your suggestion (edited my question to show my attempt), now am stuck again. Could you help ?

Comment: Wikipedia suggests: $\frac{d}{dt}\exp(H+tH)|_{t=0} = \int_0^1 \exp(\alpha X) H \exp((1-\alpha) X) \; \mathrm d \alpha$. That's quite ugly :(

Comment: If $X$ and $H$ do not commute, there is a series solution. You began it above

Comment: @WillJagy: Yes, I see now. So my error was in thinking that the derivative of the exponential map will be the exponential map again.

Comment: The proof for the integral formula  $\exp'(X)H = \int_0^1 \exp(\alpha X) H \exp((1-\alpha) X) \mathrm d\alpha$ is quite short: http://wj32.org/wp/2013/02/28/frechet-derivative-of-the-matrix-exponential-function/

Answer (score 7):

Let $f : \mathbb R^{n \times n} \to \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be defined by $f (X) = \exp(X)$. Hence,

$\begin{array}{rl} f (X + h V) &= \exp(X + h V)\\ &= I_n + (X + h V) + \frac{1}{2!} (X + h V)^2 + \frac{1}{3!} (X + h V)^3 + \cdots\\ &= I_n + X + h V + \frac{1}{2!} X^2 + \frac{h}{2!} (X V + V X) + \frac{h^2}{2!} V^2 + \frac{1}{3!} X^3 + \\ &\,\,\,\,\,+ \frac{h}{3!} (X^2 V + X V X + V X^2) + \frac{h^2}{3!} (X V^2 + V X V + V^2 X) + \frac{h^3}{3!} V^3 + \cdots\\ &= f (X) + h \left( V + \frac{1}{2!} (X V + V X) + \frac{1}{3!} (X^2 V + X V X + V X^2) + \cdots\right) + \cdots\end{array}$

Thus, the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $V$ at $X$ is given by

$$\begin{array}{rl} D_V f (X) &= \displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left( f (X + h V) - f (X) \right)\\ &= V + \frac{1}{2!} (X V + V X) + \frac{1}{3!} (X^2 V + X V X + V X^2) + \cdots\end{array}$$

We then write

$$D_V f (X) = M_0 + \frac{1}{2!} M_1 + \frac{1}{3!} M_2 + \frac{1}{4!} M_3 + \cdots$$

where

$$\begin{array}{rl} M_0 &= V\\ M_1 &= X V + V X =: \{X,V\}\\ M_2 &= X^2 V + X V X + V X^2\\ &\vdots\\ M_k &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^k X^{k-i} V X^i\end{array}$$

Answer (score -2):

The formula given by @ user251257 is closed and not so ugly, at least when $X$ is diagonalizable and we know the (eventually numerical) decomposition  $X=PDP^{-1}$ where $D=diag((\lambda_i))$. Let $f(X)=e^X$; then $Df_X(H)=\int_0^1 e^{\alpha X}He^{(1-\alpha)X} d\alpha=\int_0^1 B(\alpha) d\alpha$ is a $n\times n$ matrix; since $B(\alpha)= Pe^{\alpha D}P^{-1}HPe^De^{-\alpha D}P^{-1}$, its $(k,l)$ entry $b_{k,l}$ is in the form $\sum_{ij}u_{ij}e^{\alpha(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)}$ where $u_{ij}$ is a linear function of the $(h_{ij})$. Of course, for every $(k,l)$,  $\int_0^1 b_{kl} d \alpha$ is easy to calculate (from a numerical point of view).

Example. Let $X=\begin{pmatrix} 5.6& 0.4& 0.2\\ 0.4& 8.3& -8.5\\ 0.2& -8.5& 13.3\end{pmatrix}$ (a random symmetric $>0$ matrix) and $H=E_{1,1}$. Then

$b_{1,1}(t)\approx (.99302845389679037258*(.97923083022132240582*exp(5.6517287919679228980*t)+0.013765826093233907222*exp(1.8877987424462300666*t)+0.000031797582234059493609*exp(19.660472465585847035*t)))*exp(5.6517287919679228980-5.6517287919679228980*t)+(.11773898646801403107*(.11610306332719986462*exp(5.6517287919679228980*t)+0.0016321530422941489699*exp(1.8877987424462300666*t)+0.0000037700985200174380332*exp(19.660472465585847035*t)))*exp(1.8877987424462300666-1.8877987424462300666*t)-(0.005658693915992128895*(-0.0055800692513703492171*exp(5.6517287919679228980*t)-0.000078443468620371001349*exp(1.8877987424462300666*t)-1.8119600140866963913*10^{-7}*exp(19.660472465585847035*t)))*exp(19.660472465585847035-19.660472465585847035*t)$

and $\int_0^1b_{1,1}(t)dt\approx 1854.0328800470185607$.

Let  $\Delta=e^{A+0.001E_{1,1}}-e^A$; then $\Delta_{1,1}\approx  1.854$.