# Show that $\forall M \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R}), \exp(M) $ is $\mathcal{C}^{1}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, matrices, functional-analysis, derivatives

We define $M \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto \exp(M)=\sum _{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n!}M^n \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$.
Few ideas and though:
Is it correct that $\exp(M)$ is a polynomial? (Because of the sum and $M^n$).
Usually when we want to prove that a function is $\mathcal{C}^{1}$. We start by showing that is continuous ? (how?) and the derivative of that function is continuous and I struggle here. (Is it the same process, but with the differential in this case?)

Comment: Suppose that it is a polynomial in $M$. What is the degree of that polynomial? Do you know about power series?

Comment: I assume it's $+\infty$ but such as Formal power series

Comment: The question doesn't really make so much sense. What $\exp(M)$ be $\mathcal C^1$ means ? Do you mean $M\mapsto \exp(M)$ is $\mathcal C^1(\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R),\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R))$ ?

Comment: Yes it's true, I'm sorry for missleading you. I edit it now.

Comment: A hint to show that map is continuous is to show for M, N in $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R}), |||exp(M+H)-exp(M)|||\leqslant exp(|||M|||+|||H|||)-exp(|||M|||)$ but I struggle to prove it.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1361636/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2043/42969.

Comment: @Loca The degree of a non-zero polynomial is a non-negative integer. $+\infty$ is not a non-negative integer (or a number for that matter).

Comment: Thank you for the links, If I understand, you assume that in order to show that the function is C1, We have to prove that Dexp(M)(H) is continuous ?

Comment: @Gary Thank you for that information !

Comment: $exp(M+H)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(M+H)^{k}}{k!}=\\ \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{M^{k}}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}M^{k-j-1}HM^{j}+o(|||H|||)=\\exp(M)+Dexp(M)(H)+o(|||H|||)$ \\
In order to prove that $M \mapsto exp(M)$ is $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ let show that $Dexp(M)(H):M \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}M^{k-j-1}HM^{j}$ converge uniformly.

$|||\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}M^{k-j-1}HM^{j}|||\leqslant \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}|||M^{k-1}||| \times|||H|||=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}|||M^{k-1}||| \times|||H|||$

Comment: and $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}|||M^{k-1}||| \times|||H|||$ converge to $exp(|||M|||)\times|||H|||$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each component of $e^M$ is a power series on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ that converges absolutely everywhere because $\sum_{n}\|M^n/n!\| \leq e^{\|M\|} < \infty$. It is well known that power series are smooth. Hence each component of $e^M$ is smooth. Hence $e^M$ is smooth.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean my component of $exp(M)$ ?

Comment: @Loca The $n^2$ entries of $\exp(M)$ with respect to the standard basis.

Comment: I understand thank you