# Derivative of a Matrix Exponential with respect to A Matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus

I need to take the derivative of an exponential function with respect to a matrix.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial A} (e^{At})$

where $t$ is a scalar and $A$ is a matrix not dependent on $t$. Yes those $A$'s are the same variable for clarification.

Thank you

Comment: What is your definition for matrix derivative?

Comment: You should be able to carry out the derivative as you would do for the scalar case...For that one should use the definition of the matrix exponential

Comment: I'm not sure how best to define that. how about The derivative with respect to the elements of the matrix $A$.

Comment: Ok. Here is a better question. If I perform a series expansion of the the matrix exponential and take its derivative with respect to $A$ is the answer  $\sum_{k=1}^{\inf}A^{k-1}\frac{t^k}{k!}$

Comment: You can't take the derivitive using the limit definition, as not all nonzero matrices are invertible. So I suggest taking the infinite series, taking the derivitive treating as scalars, and then making it back a function of matrices. So we gain, informally $\frac{\delta}{\delta A} e^{At}=t e^{At}$.

Comment: Be aware that $\partial_A(A^2)(h)=hA+Ah$

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291063/derivative-of-matrix-exponential-wrt-to-each-element-of-matrix