# Derivative of $\sqrt{AA^T}$ with respect to $A$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How to find the derivative of the function $f: M_n(\mathbb{R})\to M_n(\mathbb{R}), A\mapsto \sqrt{AA^T},$ where $A^T$ is the transpose of the matrix $A$?

> \begin{align}
>     Df_V(A) & = \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(A+hV)-f(A)}{h}\\
>             & = \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{(A+hV)(A+hV)^T}-\sqrt{AA^T}}{h}\\
>             & = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{AA^T+hAV^T+hVA^T+h^2VV^T}-\sqrt{AA^T}}{h}
>   \end{align}

Now, what should I do?

Comment: The gradient would be a fourth order tensor

Comment: @user550103 why and how?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics)#Derivatives_of_tensor_valued_functions_of_second-order_tensors

Comment: @XYZABC the encode the derivative of a function you need to know all the partial derivatives. If both input and output are matrices you have a total of 4 axes to iterate over.

Comment: @Hyperplane I am not understanding what are you telling.

Comment: @XYZABC For a function $f\colon\mathbb  R^n \to\mathbb R^m$ the derivative is encoded in the matrix $\Big( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\Big)_{ij}$. If $f\colon\mathbb  R^{n\times m} \to\mathbb R^{k\times l}$ it is encoded in the 4-D tensor $\Big( \frac{\partial f_{ij}}{\partial x_{kl}}\Big)_{ijkl}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the matrix $F$ such that 
$$F = \sqrt{AA^T} \;\implies F^2 = AA^T $$
The [vec operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) can be used to flatten these matrices into vectors.
$$a={\rm vec}(A),\quad f={\rm vec}(F)$$
The requested gradient can be calculated as follows.
$$\eqalign{
&F\,F 
  &= AA^T \cr
&F\,dF\,(I)+(I)\,dF\,F
  &= A\,dA^T\,(I)+(I)\,dA\,A^T \cr
&(I^T\otimes F+F^T\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(dF)
  &= (I^T\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(dA^T)+(A\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(dA) \cr
&\Big(I\otimes F+F\otimes I\Big)\,df
  &= \Big((I\otimes A)K+(A\otimes I)\Big)\,da \cr
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}
&= \Big(I\otimes F+F\otimes I\Big)^+
\Big((I\otimes A)K+(A\otimes I)\Big) \cr\cr
}$$
where $M^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $M$, $I$ is the identity matrix, and $K$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the Kronecker product. The solution also takes advantage of the fact that $I$ and $F$ are symmetric.

The true gradient is a fourth-order tensor, while the above result is a *flattened* version of it. If you want the full tensor result, the components are not too difficult to calculate, since there is a one-to-one mapping between the elements of the tensor and the elements of the flattened matrix.

Upon re-reading the question, it looks like you are interested in the directional derivative, where changes in $A$ are restricted to the matrix direction $V$.
$$\eqalign{
v &= {\rm vec}(V) \\
df_v &= \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\bigg)\cdot v \\
}$$
Once again, *unflattening* this vector into a matrix is just a one-to-one mapping, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
F &\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \implies
f \in {\mathbb R}^{mn\times 1} \\
F_{ij} &= f_{\alpha} \\
\alpha &= i+(j-1)\,m \\
i &= 1+(\alpha-1)\,{\rm mod}\,m \\
j &= 1+(\alpha-1)\,{\rm div}\,m \\
}$$

Answer (score 3):

The biggest challenge with this derivative is that matrices do not necessarily commute. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291063) should give you a taste for the difficulties one may encounter.

Nevertheless let's give it a try. But first, generalize the problem a bit by considering the map

$$ f\colon\mathbb S^n_+\longrightarrow\mathbb S^n_+,\, X\longmapsto X^{\alpha} \overset{\text{def}}{=} \exp(\alpha\log(X))$$

which maps a symmetric, positive definite matrix to its matrix power, defined via matrix exponential and matrix logarithm. One can easily check that $\sqrt{X} = X^{1/2}$ by diagonalizing.

## 1. The commutative case

> If $\Delta X$ commutes with $X$, then everything is easy, because then $\log(X\cdot\Delta X)=\log(X) + \log(\Delta X)$ and $\exp(X+\Delta X) = \exp(X)\cdot\exp(\Delta X)$  which **does not hold true in the general case**

In the commuting case we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\log(X+\Delta X)-\log(X) 
&= \log(X+\Delta X) + \log(X^{-1}) 
\\&= \log((X+\Delta X)X^{-1}) 
\\&= \log(I+X^{-1}\Delta X)
\\&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1} \frac{(X^{-1}\Delta X)^{k}}{k}
\sim X^{-1}\Delta X \\
\exp(X+\Delta X) - \exp(X)
&= \exp(X)\exp(\Delta X) - \exp(X)
\\&= \exp(X)\big(\exp(\Delta X) -I\big)\\
&= \exp(X)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\Delta X^k \sim \exp(X)\Delta X
\end{aligned}$$
Hence $\partial_{\Delta X}\log(X) = X^{-1}$ and $\partial_{\Delta X} \exp(X) = \exp(X)$ **in the commuting case**  $[X, \Delta X]=0$. In particular via chain rule it follows that we have $\partial_{\Delta X} X^\alpha = \alpha X^{\alpha-1}$ which satisfies our expectation.

## 2. The non-commutative case

This one is much harder, one can try to use the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) and/or the [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula) but the end result won't be pretty. In general, the nice formula from before does not hold anymore. For example, if $\alpha=2$ then once can easily check that

$$(X+\Delta X)^2-X^2 \sim X\cdot\Delta X + \Delta X \cdot X \neq 2X\cdot\Delta X$$

We can verify this numerically as well, for example with the python (3.7) program below. The residuals are stable when you increase the sample size $N$ in the commutative case, but they will get larger and larger in the general case. (randomly sampling matrices with extremely large commutator is rather rare...)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import norm, fractional_matrix_power as powm
from scipy.stats import ortho_group, wishart  # to sample orthogonal/ spd matrices

alphas = np.linspace(0.5, 5, 10)
N = 100 # sample size
eps = 10**-8
n=6  # matrix size

print("Commutative case")
# using simultaneous diagonalizable => commuting
for a in alphas:
    r = 0
    for _ in range(N):
        D = np.diag(np.random.rand(n))
        S = np.diag(np.random.rand(n))
        U = ortho_group.rvs(n)
        X = U.T @ D @ U
        DX = eps* U.T@ S @ U
        num = powm(X+DX, a) - powm(X, a)  # numerical derivative
        ana = a*powm(X, a-1) @ DX         # formula
        r =max(r, norm( num-ana))
    print(F"alpha: {a:.2f}, max residual {r}")
# residuals should be numerically close to zero   

print("General case")
for a in alphas:
    r = 0
    for _ in range(N):
        X = wishart(scale=np.eye(n)).rvs()
        DX= eps*wishart(scale=np.eye(n)).rvs()
        num = powm(X+DX, a) - powm(X, a) # numerical derivative
        ana = a*powm(X, a-1) @ DX        # formula
        r =max(r, norm( num-ana))
    print(F"alpha: {a:.2f}, max residual {r}")
# residuals should be much larger
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters,$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}(AA^T)_{kl}=\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}(A_{km}A_{lm})=\delta_{ik}\delta_{jm}A_{lm}+A_{km}\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}=\delta_{ik}A_{lj}+\delta_{il}A_{kj}.$$Next, let $X:=\sqrt{AA^T}$ so $(AA^T)_{kl}=X_{kp}X_{pl}$, so$$\frac{\partial X_{kp}}{\partial A_{ij}}X_{pl}+\frac{\partial X_{pl}}{\partial A_{ij}}X_{kp}=\delta_{ik}A_{lj}+\delta_{il}A_{kj}.$$To evaluate the derivative $D_{ijrs}:=\frac{\partial X_{rs}}{\partial A_{ij}}$, note that$$D_{ijrs}(\delta_{kr}X_{sl}+\delta_{sl}X_{kr})=\delta_{ik}A_{lj}+\delta_{il}A_{kj}.$$So the result is of the form $B^{-1}C$, but with $B,\,C$ as rank-$4$ tensors rather than matrices, and their multiplication and inversion suitably defined.